How to fix ' Operation not permitted' random error using snmp4j?
I use snmp4j to query data using snmpwalk, the version is 3.7.7. Sometime it is ok,but sometime it has a error:org.snmp4j.MessageException: Operation not permitted. How to fix it? According to this question, I have try to add the iptable rule, but it is still has the error in radom.
The total error is:

org.snmp4j.MessageException: Operation not permitted at
org.snmp4j.MessageDispatcherImpl.sendPdu(MessageDispatcherImpl.java:642)
at org.snmp4j.Snmp.sendMessage(Snmp.java:1074) at
org.snmp4j.Snmp.send(Snmp.java:974) at
org.snmp4j.Snmp.send(Snmp.java:956) at
org.snmp4j.Snmp.send(Snmp.java:924)
com.iwhalecloud.uncc.util.SnmpUtil.lambda$getTableByWalkOid$0(SnmpUtil.java:581)
at
java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1700)
at
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) Caused by:
java.io.IOException: Operation not permitted at
java.base/java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.send(Native Method) at
java.base/java.net.DatagramSocket.send(DatagramSocket.java:695) at
org.snmp4j.transport.DefaultUdpTransportMapping.sendMessage(DefaultUdpTransportMapping.java:128)
at
org.snmp4j.transport.DefaultUdpTransportMapping.sendMessage(DefaultUdpTransportMapping.java:46)
at
org.snmp4j.MessageDispatcherImpl.sendMessage(MessageDispatcherImpl.java:261)
at
org.snmp4j.MessageDispatcherImpl.sendPdu(MessageDispatcherImpl.java:619)
… 10 more

